# List from list box dissapear after running macro

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have simple database with two tables, one query (to join tables) and one form for the query consisting from text box and a list box (see picture below).

[image: form example]

I am trying to use text box for searching list box while typing (as shown in this video: [youtube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cJinHSSkuI)

I copied code (with little editing of names), but for some reason it makes whole list to break (loose all entries) and won't work (screenshot of result after typing below). List won't go back to normal even after entry deletion.

[image: broken list]

What I am doing wrong?

My code:

```
Private Sub searchBox_Change()

    Dim strSource As String
    strSource = "SELECT  Paraiškos ID, Veikliosios m pavadinimas, Sugalvotas VP pavadinimas" & _
     "FROM Oldsys_Main" & _
     "Where Paraiškos ID Like '*" & Me.searchBox.Text & "*' " _
     & "Or Veikliosios m pavadinimas Like '*" & Me.searchBox.Text & "*' " _
     & "Or Sugalvotas VP pavadinimas Like '*" & Me.searchBox.Text & "*' "

    Me.oldListBox.RowSource = strSource
End Sub
```

Another (uniportant for now) question: why 5th column results are numbers? It should be text, is it because 5 column is linked with another table, is it possible to make it show text instead of ID?

Comment: Your column names have spaces in them; you need to quote them using square brackets. `SELECT [Paraiškos ID], [Veikliosios m pavadinimas], [Sugalvotas VP pavadinimas] FROM ...` -- also there should be a space between `pavadinimas` and `FROM`, as well as between `Oldsys_Main` and `Where` - your query being malformed might be contributing to the list being empty. Also... unless I'm misreading it, you're selecting 3 fields - how are you getting 6 columns?

Comment: Initially 6 fields were selected, but only 3 of them needed to be searchable, but finally after managing to run this function I noticed that list getting reduced to showing only searchable columns (for now I just add previously unsearchable columns to the sub since it is no big deal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a valid SQL syntax. Identifiers (e.g. for column names) are not allowed to have spaces or special characters other than `_`. If they have, you must enclose the name in square brackets.

There is also a space missing before `FROM` and between `Oldsys_Main` and `WHERE`, because the line breaks are within the VBA code itself, but not inside the constructed string. If you want to add line breaks in the string, you can do it with `"first line" & vbCrLf & "second line"`. But the SQL works fine on a single line.

```
Dim strSource As String, strSearch As String

strSearch = Replace(searchBox.Text, "'", "''")
strSource = "SELECT [Paraiškos ID], [Veikliosios m pavadinimas], [Sugalvotas VP pavadinimas] " _
 & "FROM Oldsys_Main " _
 & "WHERE [Paraiškos ID] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
 & "Or [Veikliosios m pavadinimas] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' " _
 & "Or [Sugalvotas VP pavadinimas] LIKE '*" & strSearch & "*' "
```

Also, replace single quotes in the search text by two single quotes to escape them. A text like `Let's go` becomes `'Let''s go'`.

---

You can test the SQL like this:

- Open the Immediate window with <kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd>.
- Copy paste the code into it and change it like this (start with a "?" which is equivalent to `Debug.Print`, replace the variable `strSearch` with a real text string (e.g. `"est"`). Then press enter

  > ?"SELECT [Paraiškos ID], [Veikliosios m pavadinimas], [Sugalvotas VP pavadinimas] " _
  >    & "FROM Oldsys_Main " _
  >    & "WHERE [Paraiškos ID] LIKE '*" & "est" & "*' " _
  >    & "Or [Veikliosios m pavadinimas] LIKE '*" & "est" & "*' " _
  >    & "Or [Sugalvotas VP pavadinimas] LIKE '*" & "est" & "*' "

  The result will print like this (on one line):

  > SELECT [Paraiškos ID], [Veikliosios m pavadinimas], [Sugalvotas VP pavadinimas] FROM Oldsys_Main WHERE [Paraiškos ID] LIKE '*est*' Or [Veikliosios m pavadinimas] LIKE '*est*' Or [Sugalvotas VP pavadinimas] LIKE '*est*'
- Copy this result into the clipboard and create a new query in design view. Switch to SQL view and paste the result into it.
- Now execute the query. You will see if if it works, or whether you get an error message. Also, syntax errors like missing spaces become apparent.

Comment: Thenk you very much it works as planned, only one additional thing I noticed that I was trying to use form name in `FROM Oldsys_Main` after trying your suggested method I understood that Query name have to be used instead, after that everything works fine. While I have some grasp on Excel and Word VBA Access is new thin for me and giving me hard time. It's like whole different language for me.

Comment: SQL (Structured Query Language) is the database language and has nothing to  do with VBA. You are only using VBA to create a string containing a SQL query. In the FROM part, you can specify either table names or query names.